# How to find difference between two integer arrays?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to write a function which returns the difference between two arrays.
The input arrays are not sorted. I'm assuming that that all elements in input arrays are unique.
For Example:

Input:  `arr1 = [1,2,3,5,4]`
        `arr2 = [1,2,3]`

Expected Output: `[4,5]`

I'm trying to implement this using an arraylist but can't find the problem with my code.
Here it is:

```
public class Difference{
ArrayList<Integer> diff(int m[],int n[])
    {
        int mlen = m.length;
        int nlen = n.length;
        ArrayList<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(m));
        ArrayList<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(n));
        if(mlen>nlen)
        {
            arr1.removeAll(arr2);
            return arr1;
        }
        else
        {
            arr2.removeAll(arr1);
            return arr2;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
          Difference obj = new Difference();
          int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
          int b[] = {1,2,3};
          System.out.println(obj.diff(a,b));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application?

Comment: @JeanLogeart Do you mean the order in the output?

Comment: Sidenote: what if both arrays are equal in length but are different in content? Your code does not handle that.

Comment: Of the input and the output?

Comment: @JeanLogeart No it doesn't matter. But consider the input arrays are not sorted.

Comment: @litelite Yes, I forgot about that condition. Thanks for reminding me about that.

Comment: what is your expectation when there are multiple matches? ie 'arr1[ 1,2,3]' 'arr2[1,1,2,3,3]' would you expect the results to be '[1,3]'?

Comment: @Jason I'm assuming there are no same elements in an array for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are trying to use a non-existing constructor for `ArrayList(int[] numbers)` You either have to add every number from `m` and `n` to the `ArrayList` or use a double brace initialization e.g.

```
ArrayList < Integer > arr1 = new ArrayList < Integer > () {
    {
        for (int i: m) add(i);
    }
}
ArrayList < Integer > arr2 = new ArrayList < Integer > () {
    {
        for (int i: n) add(i);
    }
}
```

In one line it would look like this without formatting

`new ArrayList<Integer>() {{for(int i:m) add(i);}};`

The other preferred way would be to add every number while iterating e.g.

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for(int i: m) arr1.add(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your code compile?

As someone else suggested, your ArrayList is of type Integer, not int.
Here's an edit:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
      Difference obj = new Difference();
      int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
      int b[] = {1,2,3};
      Integer[] anew = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
      Integer[] bnew = Arrays.stream(b).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
      System.out.println(obj.diff(anew,bnew));
}
```

Lastly, if you do use this, remember to change the arguments for diff to have type Integer.

Comment: Yes, it complied but didnt get any output.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is via jQuery

```
function array_diff(array1, array2){
  var diff = $(array1).not(array2).get();
  return diff;
}

console.log(array_diff([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever ends up in this question looking for an answer to the question in the title. Here is one way to do it:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int b[] = {1,2,3,6};

int[] uniqueEntries = IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(a), IntStream.of(b))
    .filter(x -> !IntStream.of(a).anyMatch(y -> y == x) || !IntStream.of(b).anyMatch(z -> z == x))
    .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(uniqueEntries));
```